# How to Find the diagonal in a list from a corresponding point

Tags: python, numpy, arraylist, chess

So, i want to find the diagonals in the list from a element(point) in the list.

my list dims are 8x8

for eg:

in the following list

[[1,2,3,4,5],

[6,7,8,9,10],

[11,12,13,14,15],

]

my point as reference for diagonal is 9

so the output should be

diagonal1 = [2,9,15] (from left point to right corner diagonal)

diagonal2 = [5,9,13]

i tried using numpy.diagonal for the same but the offset part just doesnt seems to work.

```
board_state = [
    'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r',
    'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', 'b2', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P',
    'R', 'N', 'B', 'K', 'Q', 'B', 'N', 'R'
]
def diagonals(board_state):
    board_state = np.array(board_state)
    diagonals_lst = np.diagonal(board_state.reshape([8, 8]), offset=-1)
#point of reference for now is b2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track – `np.diagonals` is well suited for this, but you need to take care computing the offsets.

In numpy (and in matrix math by convention) the diagonals run top-left to bottom-right. The main diagonal has offset 0; the diagonals above this have positive offsets, and the diagonals below have negative offsets.

That works well with standard chess notation: the square in the top-left of the board (a8) should have offset `0`, and the offset should increase by 1 if we go left, and decrease by 1 if we go down. If we compute an x offset from `a => 0, b => 1, c => 2, ...` then we can add the y offset, compensating for the fact that we want position 8 to have offset 0:

```py
    xoffset = ord(pos[0]) - ord('a')
    yoffset = int(pos[1]) - 8
    diagonal_offset = xoffset + yoffset
```

Consider then the *anti-diagonals*, running top-right to bottom-left. There are no specific numpy functions to access these – [the docs for numpy.diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) point out that we can just flip the array left to right and take the diagonal of the result. Since we're flipping left to right, the y offset in the resulting array will be the same, but the x offset will need to be flipped also (i.e. `7 - xoffset`):

```py
    antidiagonal_offset = (7 - xoffset) + yoffset
```

Putting it together we have:

```py
import numpy as np

board_state = np.array([
    'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r',
    'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', 'b2', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P',
    'R', 'N', 'B', 'K', 'Q', 'B', 'N', 'R'
]).reshape((8, 8))

def compute_offsets(pos):
    xoffset = ord(pos[0]) - ord('a')
    yoffset = int(pos[1]) - 8
    return (xoffset + yoffset, (7 - xoffset) + yoffset)

while True:
    val = input()
    diag_offset, antidiag_offset = compute_offsets(val)

    diagonals_lst = np.diagonal(board_state.reshape([8, 8]), offset=diag_offset)
    print("top-left to bottom-right", diagonals_lst)

    antidiagonals_lst = np.diagonal(np.fliplr(board_state), offset=antidiag_offset)
    print("top-right to bottom-left", antidiagonals_lst)
```

Example output:

```py
b2
  top-left to bottom-right ['' 'P' 'B']
  top-right to bottom-left ['r' 'p' '' '' '' '' 'P' 'R']
b1
  top-left to bottom-right ['P' 'N']
  top-right to bottom-left ['p' '' '' '' '' 'P' 'N']
a8
  top-left to bottom-right ['r' 'p' '' '' '' '' 'P' 'R']
  top-right to bottom-left ['r']
g6
  top-left to bottom-right ['k' 'p' '' '']
  top-right to bottom-left ['p' '' '' '' '' 'P' 'N']
```